# Android Uncaught Exception when creating a SimpleDateFormat object

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I am getting an uncaught exception when trying to call
SimpleDateFormat constructor:

```
String test = "Thu Feb 02 00:00:00 EST 2017";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss Z yyyy");
```

The stack trace is:

> 02-15 15:55:31.999 27669-27669/com.clackityclack.parseproject
>   W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
>   (group=0x40e76300) 02-15 15:55:32.077
>   27669-27669/com.clackityclack.parseproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for
>   android:onClick
>                                                                                       at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>                                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084) 
>                                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
>                                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat
>                                                                                       at
>   com.clackityclack.parseproject.childAddActivity.done(childAddActivity.java:69)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                                                                                       at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084) 
>                                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
>                                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

The imports are:

> import android.app.DatePickerDialog; import
>   android.app.DialogFragment; import android.content.Context; import
>   android.content.Intent; import android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat;
>   import android.os.Build; import
>   android.support.annotation.RequiresApi; import
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment; import
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity; import
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager; import
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; import android.os.Bundle;
>   import android.util.Log; import android.view.KeyEvent; import
>   android.view.View; import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
>   import android.widget.DatePicker; import android.widget.EditText;
>   import android.widget.TextView; import android.widget.Toast;
>
> import com.parse.ParseException; import com.parse.ParseObject; import
>   com.parse.SaveCallback;
>
> import java.io.IOException; import java.sql.SQLException; import
>   java.util.Date;
>   */
>
> import android.app.DatePickerDialog; import
>   android.app.DialogFragment; import android.content.Context; import
>   android.content.Intent; import android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat;
>   import android.os.Build; import
>   android.support.annotation.RequiresApi; import
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment; import
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity; import
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager; import
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; import android.os.Bundle;
>   import android.util.Log; import android.view.KeyEvent; import
>   android.view.View; import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
>   import android.widget.DatePicker; import android.widget.EditText;
>   import android.widget.TextView; import android.widget.Toast;
>
> import com.parse.ParseException; import com.parse.ParseObject; import
>   com.parse.SaveCallback;
>
> import java.io.IOException; import java.sql.SQLException; import
>   java.util.Date;

Comment: The error is not in the SimpleDateFormat, you have an `onClick` error. `FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick`

Comment: The "onClick" calls the function "done".  I reverted back to an earlier version of the code which is:

Answer (score 0):

Remove this import `import android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat;`

And use `import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;` instead.